# Pass data from template to related component, not to child or parent

Tags: html, css, angular

How to pass template data to related component, not to child or parent without creating a new component?

my-item.html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
 <div *ngFor="let subItem of subItems">
  <div *ngIf="!item.value.length">
   <div class="cloth {{nextAvailableSubItem}}"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

my-item.component.ts

```
 this.items = {one: ['redShirt'], two: [], three: [] four: ['whiteShirt', 'blackShirt']}
 this.subItems = ['redShirt', 'blueShirt', 'whiteShirt', 'blackShirt'];

filterItems(item, subItem){
 return nextAvailableSubItem //after redShirt should be returned whiteShirt to use the value in the template
    }
```

Comment: items, subItems, and nextAvailableSubItem
should be declared in the component itself,
and when using these variables you should add "this." before variable
like "this.items" in component.ts, 
after adding this. to these variables, you should call this method filterItems
on ngOnInt method

Comment: if you can share the whole ts file, it may help more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one common way to do it, is to share data using an observable across an intermediary service

Like Below

- **Intermediary Service:**

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
    
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class SharedDataService {
      private dataSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>('Initial Value');
      public data$: Observable<any> = this.dataSource.asObservable();
    
      updateData(newData: any): void {
        this.dataSource.next(newData);
      }
    }
```

- **First component(data sender):**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedDataService } from './shared-data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-first-component',
  template: `...`
})
export class FirstComponent {
  constructor(private sharedDataService: SharedDataService) {}

  updateSharedData(): void {
    this.sharedDataService.updateData('New Value');
  }
}
```

- **Second component(data consumer):**

```
    import { Component, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
    import { SharedDataService } from './shared-data.service';
    import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-second-component',
      template: `...`
    })
    export class SecondComponent implements OnDestroy {
      sharedData: any;
      private subscription: Subscription;
    
      constructor(private sharedDataService: SharedDataService) {
        this.subscription = this.sharedDataService.data$.subscribe(data => {
          this.sharedData = data;
          // consume data here
        });
      }
    
      ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
      }
    }
```

don't forget the unsubscribe on consumer component destroy or it would cause memory leak.

Comment: Is there a way without creating a second component?

Comment: you're sharing data between 2 or more components, so you need only those along with the intermediary service